# Column Data type is DATE, Data in csv is in DD-MM-YYYY format but while uploading date columns getting uploaded in format 2023-04-03T00:00:00.0000000

Tags: sql-server, date-formatting

Columns in my table is DATE format

I am uploading data in DD-MM-YYYY format

Using the below query:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

BULK INSERT stg.leaveapplication FROM 'qa-1/8/testdashboard/Leave dashboard/DatewiseLeaveRoster.csv'

        WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'AzureBlobStorage',

        FORMAT = 'CSV',

        FIRSTROW = 2,

        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',

        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A');
```

But my date columns are populating like 2023-04-03T00:00:00.0000000 and blank columns are populating like 1900-01-01T00:00:00.0000000

I was expecting my values to be loaded in DD-MM-YYYY format and blank value where it is blank.
But I am getting 2023-04-03T00:00:00.0000000 and blank columns are populating like 1900-01-01T00:00:00.0000000

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format. they are binary values. The aren't "populating like 2023-04-03T00:00:00.0000000" that's the format SSMS is using to display the date and time value. When you build your application, you'll put logic in that to denote what *format* it will use.

Comment: Date is a 4-byte binary structure in the database. The display format is controlled by the application presenting the value. Empty strings indicate a [default value for date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (1900-01-01).

Comment: `I was expecting` the expectation is wrong. Dates are binary values, they have no format. `1900-01-01` is the "zero" date when using the legacy `datetime` type. If you want just dates, use the correct type, `date`. In `datetime` the binary value stored in the column is an offset (positive or negative) from the "zero" date. If the date field was nullable you'd get a NULL, not the "zero" date. In general, avoid using `datetime`. Use `datetime2`, `date`, `time` or `datetimeoffset`

Comment: I also can't replicate your problem with columns having the value `1900-01-01` being inserted into the column for empty string values. For rows with the values `,2021-09-10` and `"",2021-09-11` the value `NULL` was insert into the first column. Perhaps you have a `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT` on your column which defaults it to `1900-01-01`? If so, you'll need to use `KEEPNULLS` in your `WITH` clause; though this will overide **all** `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT`s.

Comment: `1900-01-01` is the "zero" date for the very quirky `datetime` type. The actual representation is a float offset from `1900-01-01` and can be cast implicitly to/from floats. This allows some hacks but also a lot of bugs. If the file contains `""` instead of an empty field, that `""` is parsed as the number `0`, which is the actual value of `1900-01-01`. `select cast('' as float)` returns `0`. `select cast('' as datetime)` returns `1900-01-01`

Comment: If the file contains `,"",` instead of `,,` then it's a *file bug*, one of those causing the $100K bills. `""` isn't a missing value, it's a very specific *text* value. `"` is used to delimit text fields, especially those that may contain unexpected values like newlines, commas - or be empty. The file itself is saying that this field isn't empty but contains an empty string.

Comment: *"that `""` is parsed as the number `0`"* This statement is incorrect, @PanagiotisKanavos . If you test, you'll see that (at least with `FORMAT = 'CSV'`) that both `,,` and `,"",` are parsed as empty strings and both result in `NULL` (on a `NULL`able column with no `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT`).

Comment: The `date`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset` types don't allow implicit casts like this and would have thrown errors.

Comment: @ThomA `incorrect` I actually included the cast examples. You may be able to come up with better wording, but it's not incorrect. If you check, `datetime` does use the float OADate format, it does allow implicit casts and arithmetic.

Comment: [Screenshot for proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3EA6.png) that `""` <> `0` <> `1900-01-01` @PanagiotisKanavos . This behaviour occurs for `datetime` as well as `date`. So having `""` for an empty string is *not* a "file bug"; it's a quote identified value in a CSV file, and SQL Server is able to parse that correctly as `NULL`.

Comment: @ThomA that screenshot doesn't reproduce the OP's problem. I wasn't talking about BULK INSERT anyway, I was talking about the `datetime` type and its quirks

Comment: You *are* talking about the file, @PanagiotisKanavos , you explicitly talk about a "file bug".

Comment: And I *know* it doesn't replicate the issue, because ([as I stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76414889/column-data-type-is-date-data-in-csv-is-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-but-while-uploadin#comment134744460_76414889)) I have been unable to replicate the OP's behaviour [without the use of a `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuBR5.png).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos MySQL will parse an empty string as the number 0. SQL Server will not do that. But MySQL also has a different default datetime value (0000-00-00 instead of 1900-01-01)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn this is a SQL Server question, and `select cast('' as float)` works on SQL Server 2019. So does `select cast('' as datetime)`. Unfortunately so does `select cast('' as date)` which I expected to just fail! Only `PARSE` fails on empty strings. What does MySQL have to do with the question?

Answer (score 1):

`Date` columns in SQL Server **NEVER** preserve any kind of human-readable format. Any original format provided at insert/update time is *always* lost. *This is a good thing.* Instead, these columns store values in a compact binary format that is efficient for storage, memory use, indexing, and date math operations.

Any other format you see, such as the `2023-04-03T00:00:00.0000000` value from the question, is a convenience provided by your tooling. If the format matters, then specify that format again at the point when you query the data (hint: you're usually better off letting the client code or reporting tool worry about the format, and just return the raw value).

The one thing that is surprising is seeing `1900-01-01` for the blank values. Typically, I would expect a database `NULL` here. Again, this could be an artifact of the tool you're using to view the data.

Comment: The [default date value of 1900-01-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-description) is used for empty strings. To wit, `SELECT CAST('' AS date)` returns `1900-01-01`

Comment: I just found that and I was very, very surprised. I guess 18 years ago that make sense to make migration from `datetime` to `date` easier. Except things didn't work that way

Comment: But an empty string in a CSV file doesn't default to `1900-01-01`, @DanGuzman, it defaults to `NULL`. For a zero length literal string, yes, but that's not the behaviour the OP is asking about here.